# How to capture the repeating operands of a multiplication using python regex

Tags: python, regex

I am processing equations using python regex.
I want to capture the repeating operands of the multiplication like below

```
5*5 --> 5  
3.14*4 --> no return  
(10-4)*(10-4) --> (10-4)
```

I found individual patterns to address the scenarios with or without parenthese

```py
pattern = r"(?=(?:\D|\b))(\d+)\*\1(?=(?:\D|\b))"

re.findall(pattern, "15*15") # ['15']
re.findall(pattern, "3.14*4") # []

pattern = r"(\([\d\-\+]+\))\*\1"
re.findall(pattern, "(10-4)*(10-4)") # ['(10-4)']
```

But I found it's tricky that I cannot combine both patterns together,
either by alternation (`|`) or `?` quantifier.

```py
pattern = r"(?=(?:\D|\b))(\d+)\*\1(?=(?:\D|\b))|(\([\d\-\+]+\))\*\1"  # Alternation

re.findall(pattern, "15*15")  # [('15', '')]
re.findall(pattern, "3.14*4") # []
re.findall(pattern, "(10-4)*(10-4)") # []

pattern = r"(?=(?:\D|\b))(\(?[\d\-\+]+\)?)\*\1(?=(?:\D|\b))" # with ? for parenthese

re.findall(pattern, "15*15")  # ['15']
re.findall(pattern, "3.14*4") # []
re.findall(pattern, "(10-4)*(10-4)") # []
```

Is there any workaround or should I have to do it seperately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
(?<!\d)(\d+)\*\1(?!\d)|(\([\d+-]+\))\*\2
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/coMpsZ/1). Details:

- `(?<!\d)(\d+)\*\1(?!\d)` - Any one or more digits (captured into Group 1) not enclosed with digits, followed with a `*` char and then the same number as in Group 1 (not followed with a digit
- `|` - or
- `(\([\d+-]+\))\*\2` - Group 2, capturing `(`, then one or more digits, `-` or `+` and then a `)` char, then matches a `*` char and the same value as in Group 2.

In Python, use

```py
import re
rx = r"(?<!\d)(\d+)\*\1(?!\d)|(\([\d+-]+\))\*\2"
texts = ["5*5", "3.14*4", "(10-4)*(10-4)"]
for text in texts:
  print( [f'{x.group(1) or ""}{x.group(2) or ""}' for x in re.finditer(r'(?<!\d)(\d+)\*\1(?!\d)|(\([\d+-]+\))\*\2', text)] )
```

See the [online Python demo](https://ideone.com/nxSlkE). Output:

```
['5']
[]
['(10-4)']
```

Comment: This doesn't match the desired output.

Comment: @Kraay89 Thanks, I am so used to returning the whole match in scenarios like this that it slipped my attention. Fixed.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you! I think I got my issues. I should have changed the `\1` to `\2` in my second last answer in order to get the second match. But yours is more clear and readable.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sure!!

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
(?<!\d)((\()?\d+(?:[.-]\d+)?(?(2)\)))\*\1(?!\d)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<!\d)` Assert not a digit directly to the left
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `(\()?` Optionally match `(` in **group 2**
  - `\d+` Match 1+ digits
  - `(?:[.-]\d+)?` Optionally match `.` or `-` and 1+ digits
  - `(?(2)\))` Match `)` if group 2 exists
- `)` Close group 1
- `\*\1` Match `*` followed by a backreference what is captured in group 1
- `(?!\d)` Assert not a digit directly to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uLIfD9/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/W0Fw92)

```
import re
 
regex = r"(?<!\d)((\()?\d+(?:[.-]\d+)?(?(2)\)))\*\1(?!\d)"
 
test_str = ("5*5 --> 5  \n"
    "3.14*4 --> no return  \n"
    "(10-4)*(10-4) --> (10-4)")
 
for m in re.finditer(regex, test_str):
    print(m.group(1))
```

Output

```
5
(10-4)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Actually there still needs a lookahead for input like `44*444`. But this answer really solves my problem to merge these two patterns together. I'm still considering whether to keep things simple with alternation or just put everything together.

Comment: @Hong In that case, you can add a negative lookahead at the end to assert not a digit `(?<!\d)((\()?(\d+(?:[.-]\d+)?)(?(2)\)))\*\1(?!\d)` https://regex101.com/r/B8psG4/1